# Validating spring config xml Files in Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing

i want to validate some files looking like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd />

...
<bean>...</bean>
...
</beans>
```

Some of them have more xmlns and locations and some less. Someone knows if there is any api where u just give in such files and it will validate it in java?

greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/package-summary.html

You can wrap it and make parser that will first extract schemas, then use them for validation.

Comment: Thought about that too but though i dont realy know what i have to do with this xmlns i thought there might be somesthing that already does that all this validations^^

Comment: Validator needs xmlns to know what to validate. Same as spellchecker needs vocabulary :)

Answer (score 1):

Spring will validate spring configuration files.  You can write a junit that loads your configuration to test if the configuration files are formatted correctly.

Comment: Well i need to do it directly from a program thats the problem with it :P

Comment: Define "directly from a program".  If you want to be the one validating the spring configuration, then write a SAX parser for it.

Comment: SAX should handle the XMLNS stuff for you if it is namespace aware

Comment: I get a file like this from an editor it is handed over to an action inserting this file into a DB. But i want to validate it before it goes into the DB to eliminate at least some possible errors the user can do. In fact i dont even have real files (which shouldnt matter) but a String object containing the XML content.